# Is responding to requests with a past modal verb considered impolite?

Tags: modal-verbs

1. Would you open the door? (Polite request)

1a.  Yes, I would.(Is this sentence considered impolite because using "would" subtly hints it or
gives a feeling that the responder is being cheeky?)

Similarly,

2. Could you switch off the fan? (Polite request)

2a. Yes, I could. (Should it be "yes, I can" to not sound impolite or cheeky?)

Comment: _Yes, I will_ sounds better for the first one.

Comment: Does 1a and 2a sound impolite?

Comment: They sound so odd that it is hard to infer that they were meant to be rude.

Comment: Between friends, the responder could just be echoing the other person's words in a mildly humorous way. If it's a polite request from someone they don't know well, they would probably say "Certainly", "Of course", or simply do it without saying anything.

Comment: Does 1a and 2a sound rude/cheeky? Also if someone asked "Would you like some tea" and I said " I wouldn't", Would that be considered rude ?? As we use "would" to show politeness, can we use "would not" for politely refusing a request or offer?

Comment: @PeterM.-standsforMonica Why not "yes, I would" (perhaps with a "please" or "thank you" thrown in somewhere)?

Comment: The response to "would you x" is Yes, I will. And the response to "Could you x" can be many things: Yes, I can. Yes, sure. Could and should don't really work here pragmatically. Though they can: Would you like to buy me dinner? Yes, I would.

Answer (score 1):

Answering with the same form ("would", "could") keeps the answer subjunctive implying that you not necessarily will.

Consider the joke.

Interview for a job:
A: "What's your greatest weakness?"
B: "Interpreting semantics of a question,
but ignoring the pragmatics."
A: "Could you give an example?"
B: "Yes, I could."

Comment: Nice example, but you're not really answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both responses are a bit cheeky, though I feel the second is cheekier than the first.

In both cases, it sounds like you are taking the question too literally. The other person is requesting an *action*, but you are responding as though they requested  *information*.

> Would you open the door? (Polite request)
>
> Yes, I would. (I agree that, under this set of circumstances, I would in theory choose to open the door.)

> Could you switch off the fan? (Polite request)
>
> Yes, I could. (I agree that it is possible for me to switch off the fan.)

If you say these things *while* you are doing the requested action, it will probably be taken as a joke. If you say these things and then *don't* do the requested action, that will definitely be seen as rude.

For small, easy tasks like these that can be completed immediately, it is typical to respond with a simple affirmation. "Yes", "Sure", "Of course", "Certainly", etc.

---

In the opposite situation, where someone is offering to do something for you, the rules are a bit different. If someone asks you a " 'would' question", you *can* respond with "would" in turn, though it's not required.

> Would you like some tea? (Polite offer)

> Yes, I would. Thank you. (Polite acceptance)
>
> *- OR -*
>
> Yes, thank you. (Polite acceptance)
>
> *- OR -*
>
> No, thank you. (Polite refusal)

But for " 'could' questions", you should still avoid saying "could" in return.

> Could I get you some more water? (Polite offer)

> Yes, thank you. (Polite acceptance)
>
> *- OR -*
>
> No, thank you. (Polite refusal)
>
> *- NOT -*
>
> <s>Yes, you could.</s> (Cheeky!)

---

In both cases, repeating "could" is cheekier than repeating "would" because it implies that you are criticizing the speaker's grammar. Some people insist that "can" and "could" should only be used to describe whether or not someone is *capable* of doing something, and that any other use is wrong:

> <s>Could you</s> **Would you** switch off the fan? (Polite request)
>
> <s>Could I get you</s> **Would you like** some more water? (Polite offer)
>
> <s>Can I</s> **May I** use your restroom? (Asking permission)

In casual conversation, the vast majority of native speakers don't care about this rule. But if you repeat "could" in your answer, they might think that you are trying to call attention to their "mistake".

(For example: if you were a grammar snob *and* very sarcastic, you might respond to the question "Can I use your restroom?" with "I don't know, *can* you?")

Answer (score 1):

The grammatical form "past modal" is irrelevant: the point is that these are answering the literal question instead of the implied request (Another example which does not use a past modal is "Are you going to give me the book?" "Yes, I am" (but carries on reading it)).

This is a violation of the [conversational implicature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature) of *Relevance*. Violating a conversational implicature *can* be impolite, but it depends very much on context, and on the relationship between the people: it might be an old joke between them, for exaple.